# Save formset in an UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views

I have the models `Entry` and `Meaning` below with many-to-many relation. I need to create an update form/view to edit `Entry` and `Meaning` objects at the same time. I have also to be able to add more `Meaning` objects to an `Entry` object while editing it.
I tried to use `UpdateView` and `modelformset_factory` as below.

I can see the forms, but my view doesn't save the `Meaning` changes. I have two questions:

1. How do I save the `Meaning` changes?
2. How do I add or delete a `Meaning` object in this form/view?

#### Models

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug = models.SlugField('slug', max_length=100, unique=True)

class Meaning(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
    entry = models.ManyToManyField(
        Entry, related_name='meaning', 
        related_query_name='meanings',
        through='MeaningRelation')

class MeaningRelation(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meaning = models.ForeignKey(Meaning, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

#### Forms

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        fields = ['title', 'slug']

MeaningFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.Meaning, fields=('title', 'language'))
```

#### View

```
class EntryUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Entry
    form_class = forms.EntryForm
    formset_class = forms.MeaningFormSet
    template_name = 'edit.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        qs = models.Meaning.objects.filter(entry=self.get_object())
        formset = forms.MeaningFormSet(queryset=qs)
        context['meaning_formset'] = formset
        return context
```

#### Template

```
# edit.html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}

    {{ meaning_formset.management_form }}
    {% for meaning_form in meaning_formset %}
        {{ meaning_form.as_p }}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem adding the `post` method to `EntryUpdateView` class:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    qs = models.Meaning.objects.filter(entry=self.get_object())
    formsets = forms.MeaningFormSet(self.request.POST, queryset=qs)

    if form.is_valid():
        for fs in formsets:
            if fs.is_valid():
                fs.save()
        return self.form_valid(form)
    return self.form_invalid(form)
```